# how to add web api service to sencha 6 website project

Tags: extjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have website produced by sencha 6 with cmd 
so when I need to connect with server so I added web api service 
but I created it with separate project 
so how can I add this service to my sencha project 
here's a pic to show my project structure
 [image: describe]

Comment: Configure your store URL to your endpoint URL of your web service API, set proxy type as REST, auto sync, autoload in true. please read all documentation here http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.Store and there is an example of how to configure your stores